# Make virtualBox webserver public

Tags: nat, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I'm new to virtualBox so please bear with me.

I have a win 7 Ultimate N host (my physical machine)
I have a virtual machine with win 2008 server running sharepoint which I want to access from public internet.

My Host virtual IP: 192.168.56.1
My Host physical IP: 192.168.0.15

MY Virtual machine (Guest) IP: 192.168.56.102

WHat I have done so far....

1. Activated NAT adapter and using the port forward option:
   Host: 192.168.56.1
   Host port: 10000
   Guest: 192.168.56.102
   Guest port: 80
2. On my router/modem's firewall forwarded port 10000 requests to: 192.168.0.15
3. Rebooted Virtual Machine.

However, when I browse even from my physical machine to: 192.168.0.15:10000 nothing happens. And when I click diagnose in IE, it finally gives me: "The remote device or resource wont accept the connection".

I can browse the sharepoint site from my physical machine by using the virtual box ip address and machine name: 192.168.56.102

SO I turned off windows firewall, but still mo joy.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider switching the guest over to using bridged networking instead. This means the guest will request it's own address from your NAT:ing modem. If you can tell your modem to assign a specific IP, you can then make sure your server gets a persistent address that the modem can forward too.

This of course still requires firewalls to be properly configured or turned off.

Comment: Do i need to get my modem to assign an ip to the guest machine?

Comment: OK after changing to bridged connection, my guest gets assigned an ipaddress from the modem automatically (192.168.0.13). I can now browse the website using this ipaddress however, after I put a port forwarding rule into my modem/router to send any requests for port 12000 to this ip address, i cannot access the website using my <public ip>:12000